# MacOS: How to run Bitcoin Core GUI after building from source?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I built Bitcoin Core from source by following this guide: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

And got it running on the command line via: `./src/bitcoind`

Screenshots from https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node indicate that there is a GUI.

[image: Bitcoin GUI screenshot]

However, the guide does not mention (at the time of writing this) how to get the GUI running.

So where do I find it? How do I run it?

Comment: The GUI binary is called `bitcoin-qt`, not `bitcoind`.

Comment: @PieterWuille I don't see that binary alongside `bitcoind`. Any particular reason `bitcoin-qt` wouldn't get built along with everything else?

Comment: For example because you don't have Qt5 development files installed.

Comment: @PieterWuille I followed the official build guide (link in OP). What should I be doing differently to ensure "Qt5" files get installed?

Comment: It does tell you to install qt using brew, so I suspect it should just work. Note that the qt binary will be in the src/qt/ subdirectory. If it's not there, I can't help you as I don't have Mac hardware.

Comment: Yes, I did install the `qt` dependency with `brew`, as per the guide. I do see lots of files in the `src/qt/` folder, however no binary named `bitcoin-qt` there.